# How to count duplicate entries in a .csv file?

Tags: java, csv, parsing

I have a .csv file that is formated like this:

```
ID,date,itemName
456,1-4-2020,Lemon
345,1-3-2020,Bacon
345,1-4-2020,Sausage
123,1-1-2020,Apple
123,1-2-2020,Pineapple
234,1-2-2020,Beer
345,1-4-2020,Cheese
```

I have already implemented the algorithm to go through the file, scan for the first number and sort it in a descending order and make a new output:

```
123,1-1-2020,Apple
123,1-2-2020,Pineapple
234,1-2-2020,Beer
345,1-3-2020,Bacon
345,1-4-2020,Cheese
345,1-4-2020,Sausage
456,1-4-2020,Lemon
```

My question is, how do I implement my algorithm to make an output that counts the duplicate first number entries and reformat it to make it look like this...

```
123,1-1-2020,1,Apple
123,1-2-2020,1,Pineapple
234,1-2-2020,1,Beer
345,1-3-2020,1,Bacon
345,1-4-2020,2,Cheese,Sausage
456,1-4-2020,1,Lemon
```

...so that it counts the number of occurrence for each ID, denote it with the number of times, and if the date of that ID is also the same, combine the item names to the same line. Below is my source code (each line in the .csv is made into an object named 'receipt' that has ID, date, and name with their respective get() methods):

```
public class ReadFile {

    private static List<Receipt> readFile() {
        
        List<Receipt> receipts = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dataset.csv"));

            // Move past the first title line
            reader.readLine();

            String line = reader.readLine();

            // Start reading from second line till EOF, split each string at ","
            while (line != null) {
                String[] attributes = line.split(",");
                Receipt attribute = getAttributes(attributes);
                receipts.add(attribute);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return receipts;
    }

    private static Receipt getAttributes(String[] attributes) {

        // Get ID located before the first ","
        long memberNumber = Long.parseLong(attributes[0]);

        // Get date located after the first ","
        String date = attributes[1];

        // Get name located after the second ","
        String name = attributes[2];

        return new Receipt(memberNumber, date, name);
    }

    // Parse the data into new file after sorting
    private static void parse(List<Receipt> receipts) {
        PrintWriter output = null;
        try {
            output = new PrintWriter("output.txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // For each receipts, assert the text output stream is not null, print line.
        for (Receipt p : receipts) {
            assert output != null;
            output.println(p.getMemberNumber() + "," + p.getDate() + "," + p.getName());
        }
        assert output != null;
        output.close();
    }

    // Main method, accept input file, sort and parse
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Receipt> receipts = readFile();
        QuickSort q = new QuickSort();
        q.quickSort(receipts);
        parse(receipts);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your output.  You have 345 on two separate lines on the output.  I thought the first number was the one used to combine the lines.

Comment: Never store dates as MM-DD-YYYY or DD-MM-YYYY. Always ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD).

Comment: @jarmod  It may be a requirement that the OP has no control over.

Comment: @WJS it's because they have different dates so their respective items are not being combined into one line. Only the ones with the same ID and date is combined.

Comment: @Mint  Then why did you combine apple and pineapple in the first line.  Two different dates.

Comment: @WJS it's my bad, they're not supposed to. I will fix the example right now, thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: @WJS yes, but the sooner every programmer learns the basics of date representation, the better.

Comment: @jarmod I was given the file with over 40.000 entries and as WJS said, I had no control over it, but I appreciate the information and will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a map.

Sample data from your file.

```
String[] lines = {
"123,1-1-2020,Apple",
"123,1-2-2020,Pineapple",
"234,1-2-2020,Beer",
"345,1-3-2020,Bacon",
"345,1-4-2020,Cheese",
"345,1-4-2020,Sausage",
"456,1-4-2020,Lemon"};
```

- Create a map
- as you read the lines, split them and add them to the map using the `compute` method. This will put the line in if the key (number and date) doesn't exist.  Otherwise it simply appends the last item to the existing entry.
- the file does not have to be sorted but the values will be added to the end as they are encountered.

```
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>(); 
for (String line : lines) {
    String[] vals = line.split(",");

    // if v is null, add the line
    // if v exists, take the existing line and append the last value
    map.compute(vals[0]+vals[1], (k,v)->v == null ? line : v +","+vals[2]);
}

for (String line : map.values()) {
    String[] fields = line.split(",",3);
    int count = fields[2].split(",").length;
    System.out.printf("%s,%s,%s,%s%n", fields[0],fields[1],count,fields[2]);
}
```

For this sample run prints

```
123,1-1-2020,1,Apple
123,1-2-2020,1,Pineapple
234,1-2-2020,1,Beer
345,1-3-2020,1,Bacon
345,1-4-2020,2,Cheese,Sausage
456,1-4-2020,1,Lemon
```